# Remove tab from text area when populated with cell data from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Im having trouble with this bit of code:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="45" name="edit_bio" >
        <?php 
            foreach ($query as $row) {
            $bio_text = $row['bio'];
            $bio_text = str_replace("\t", '', $bio_text);

            echo $bio_text; }
        ?>
        </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
```

Basically what is happening is the textarea shows the contents of the cell from my database but for some reason it adds several tabs around all of the strings in the cell. There's no tabs in the cell, and as you can see I tried using the string replace function to get rid of  the tabs in the text area. This doesn't work though.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using tabs in your editor?  If so, it might help to change it to this:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="45" name="edit_bio" ><?php 
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $bio_text = $row['bio'];
        $bio_text = str_replace("\t", '', $bio_text);
        echo $bio_text;
    }
?></textarea>
```

Comment: @pwneth : Can you show me the difference? I can not see any difference between your code and the code from rtcherry?

Comment: rtcherry just got rid of the tabs between the end of the html and start of the <?php tags and between the end of the php tag and the start of the html